# Dwarves sleeping on floor in dormitory

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I have a bedroom designated as a dormitory in my dwarves' fortress. The room has 7 beds, none of them assigned to anyone. Yet everyone is sleeping on the floor. In fact, at this time, there are seven dwarves in the dirt snoozing away. What's going on here?

Comment: I can think of a couple of user oversights that could result in this behavior. The simplest is forgetting to hit the 'd' key in the room's menu to change it from a simple bedroom with a lot of extra beds to an actual dormitory. Another is if the beds somehow got forbidden.

Comment: The room is marked as a dormitory for sure. How would the beds become forbidden?

Comment: Well the components of buildings can become forbidden from area select forbid commands. It's unlikely but possible. There is a reason I didn't post as an answer.

Comment: Dwarf fortress has a lot of semi-hidden internal state. Many people suggest posting a screenshot or save file if they don't have a lot of details to add textually for questions like this. I hesitate to suggest this because it leads to dependencies on offsite (and potentially temporary) resources for understanding the question fully, but it does let people poke around and rule out incorrect answers more quickly.